# Как ajax написать на vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как переделать данный код на vanilla javascript, без использования jquery.

```
let url = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${API_KEY}

    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#btn").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#results").empty();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#btn").attr("disabled", false);
            displayVideos(data);
        },
    });
```

Comment: Уж лучше [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше используйте [fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch):

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: лучше чем что?.

Comment: @Grundy, Чем `XMLHttpRequest`

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться XMLHttpRequest

Посмотрите здесь
[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]